# Page template for a form in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hi what is the best page template to use for a page having a form in Hybris?Should you go for some out of the box template or create a new one?

Comment: you can use `ContentPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContentPage` to create your page.

You can choose OOTB page template(e.g. ContentPage1Template) if it's layout fits with your requirement or create your custom. Make sure, ContentPage type is not restricted for your page template. Which can be checked with restrictedPageTypes of PageTemplate.

```
# Create PageTemplates                                                                                     
# These define the layout for pages                                                                        
# "FrontendTemplateName" is used to define the JSP that should be used to render the page for pages with multiple possible layouts.
# "RestrictedPageTypes" is used to restrict templates to page types    

INSERT_UPDATE PageTemplate ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; uid[unique=true]                     ; name                                      ; frontendTemplateName              ; restrictedPageTypes(code) ; active[default=true]
                           ;                         ; ContentPage1Template                 ; Content Page 1 Template                   ; layout/contentLayout1Page         ; ContentPage
```

You can refer faq content page, which is created using ContentPage1Template page template.

```
# Simple Content Pages    
INSERT_UPDATE ContentPage ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; uid[unique=true] ; name                                ; masterTemplate(uid,$contentCV) ; label ; defaultPage[default='true'] ; approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'] ; homepage[default='false']
                          ;                         ; faq              ; Frequently Asked Questions FAQ Page ; ContentPage1Template           ; /faq
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.However I had a confusion if we need to edit the frontend template field for the already existing ContentPage1Template.Will we mention our page(which we are creating)there?Will it hamper other pages?Where will we write the tags in the page or in the template?

Comment: Its advisable to make your changes at page level if it only relevant for your custom(new) page

Comment: ,is it possible to rename this page template so that is displayed differently in SmartEdit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new CMSComponent which contains the form.